# How to Delete a record using a ID?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to delete a record depending on the ID value.

Right now it always deletes the first record even if i choose the second record.

How do I make it work to delete the correct record?

```
 <cfloop query="GetRecipients">
            <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id" value="1" id="deleteid"></td>              
                    <td> <a href=""  name="deleteid"  class="deleteidhere" >Remove</a></td>

            </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="id" value="2" id="deleteid"></td>        
          <td> <a href=""  name="deleteid"  class="deleteidhere" >Remove</a></td>

      </tr>
        </cfloop>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".deleteidhere").click(function(e){

    //  alert(deleteid);
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete record?")){

          e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({type: "POST",
                url: "delete_check_Recipents.cfc?method=deleteids",
                data: { id: $("#deleteid").val() },
                success:function(result){
          $("#deleteidhere").html(result);
          window.location.href = "dates.cfm?recipient";
        }});

        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
      })


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Because an `id` is supposed to be unique you should not have duplicates. If there are duplicates it will [only get the first one](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Uses classes and `$(this)` when referring to the clicked element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same id for both records. I have changed this below to get the right element. Using the same id to more than one element is not recommended. Hence replace the id below with a class name and also in the html.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".deleteidhere").click(function(e){

    //  alert(deleteid);
          var elm = $(this).closest('tr').find("#deleteid"); // replace a css class here
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete record?")){

          e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({type: "POST",
                url: "delete_check_Recipents.cfc?method=deleteids",
                data: { id: elm.val() },
                success:function(result){
          $("#deleteidhere").html(result);
          window.location.href = "dates.cfm?recipient";
        }});

        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
      })


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'class' instead of 'id', the 'id' is supposed to be unique